# Related theorems of the monotone class theorem

Tags: measure-theory, monotone-class-theorem

The monotone class theorem in my measure theory text book is stated as follows.

> $\mathcal{C}$ is a family of sets. If $\mathcal{C}$ is an algebra, then $m(\mathcal{C}) = \sigma(\mathcal{C})$, where $m(\mathcal{C})$ *resp.* $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ is the smallest monotone class *resp.* $\sigma-$algebra that contains $\mathcal{C}$.

And there are 2 related theorems below it:

> If $\mathcal{C}$ is a family of sets satisfying $A \in \mathcal{C} \Rightarrow A^c \in m(\mathcal{C})$ and $A,B \in \mathcal{C} \Rightarrow A\cap B \in m(\mathcal{C})$, then $m(\mathcal{C}) = \sigma(\mathcal{C})$. ($A^c$ is the complement of $A$.)
>
> If $\mathcal{C}$ is a family of sets satisfying $A \in \mathcal{C} \Rightarrow A^c \in m(\mathcal{C})$ and $A,B \in \mathcal{C} \Rightarrow A\cup B \in m(\mathcal{C})$, then $m(\mathcal{C}) = \sigma(\mathcal{C})$.

I wonder how to prove these 2 theorems. Is it possible to prove them from monotone class theorem? Or must they be proven from scratch, like the proof of the monotone class theorem, by proving that $m(\mathcal{C})$ is a $\sigma-$algebra.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If one couldn't deduce them from the previous result, then they wouldn't be *corollaries* of it.

Comment: I referred to my textbook again. These 2 theorems are labelled as 'theorem' but not 'corollary'. I'm sorry for the mistake and I have corrected it.

Comment: Nonetheless you can prove them using the monotone class theorem and the (obvious ?) fact that $m(m(\mathcal{C})) = m(\mathcal{C})$